# How to print the string that has lowest ascii sum out of other possibilities

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, data-structures, ascii

I am writing a program that creates string of length n with x distinct values however it's required that the string created should have lowest ascii sum , my code creates n length string with x distinct values but it doesn't create lowest ascii valued string, help is required what am i doing wrong

```
int main()
```

```
  int n,x;
  int p= 97;
  cin>>n;
  cin>>x;
  if (n<x || x==1){

    cout<< "00";
  }
  else {


    for(int j = 0; j<n ; j++)
  {
      char ans = (char)(p+(j%x));
      cout << ans;
  }
  }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to have `x` distinct characters but need the lowest ASCII value string, you need to make a simple observation: greedily insert as many 'a' as you can (`n-x+1`, to be precise). Since you need `x-1` distinct characters other than 'a', proceed to insert 'b', 'c' and so on, in sequential order.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
char ans = (char)(p + (j % 26));
```

Comment: that doesn't help as its required to have x distinct values if i change x to 26 in the loop